# How to use check statements so new rows in a table are checked against a column in another table

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints, bulkinsert

I had some limited success using foreign key. I have a 'Colour' table and a 'Car' table, the colour table is permanent and the car table is where new rows will be added by clients. I want to ensure new 'Colour' column entries in car table are checked against Colour table so that no new colours can be added to Car table. The SQL should present an error if the Colour entry in car table does not match with set colour column data in Colour table.

Also, how can I get it working using BULK INSERT statement

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are running: mysql, sql-server, oracle...?

Comment: You should give a sample code of what you got so far so answers can relate to your current solution.

Answer (score 1):

A foreign key will do just that. A [very] simplistic example could go like this:

```
create table color (
  name varchar(50) primary key not null
);

create table car (
  id primary key not null,
  color_name varchar(50) not null,
  constraint fk1 foreign key (color_name) references color (name)
);
```

Then, you can insert data:

```
insert into color (name) values ('orange');
insert into color (name) values ('yellow');
insert into color (name) values ('magenta');

insert into car (id, color_name) values (10, 'orange'); -- succeeds
insert into car (id, color_name) values (11, 'magenta'); -- succeeds
insert into car (id, color_name) values (12, 'purple'); -- fails!
```

As expected, the last insert will fails, since there's no purple color.